# Is there a functional difference between the modern police station and classic police station?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

A villager requested that I create a police station as our next public works project, which I would be happy to oblige... but I've got some questions first.  That conversation unlocked the "modern police station" and "classic police station" and both will cost 264,000 to construct.  Is there any functional difference between the two?  Can I build both, or will I be restricted to one or the other?  Is one better to have than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Modern Police Station gives you Copper, and the Classic gives you Booker as your constable. So aesthetics aside, what you want to do really is choose which of the two you get in town.

More info: http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Police_Station

Answer (score 1):

The modern police station has Copper, and the classic police station has Booker. There's no functional difference.

Answer (score 0):

No, exept that the classic police station has booker and is made of wood, and the modern one has copper and is made of some sort of metal...